# Set Default Version in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

HELP!

Google has recently depreciated their AppEngine Console (https://appengine.google.com), and the link to a page that allowed setting the version of an application now goes to a new page which does not. (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=...).

Do we have to split traffic to change versions?

Do we use the Google Cloud Shell?

Is this temporary?

Is this documented someplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You click the migrate traffic button on this page you linked. This is the same workflow as what was in the old UI. If you want to brute force it, open up the advanced options section.

[image]